# React Native ScrollView within Overlay not scrolling

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview, react-native-elements

I'm using the Overlay component from react-native-elements which is supposed to be built over the underlying react-native Modal component. I have tried to place a simple ScrollView within the Overlay but the content just renders till the end of the Overlay and truncates the rest of it.

I suspect it might be a style issue but I have looked through all the possible props without luck.

```
<Overlay style={{height: height - 20, width: width}}>
<ScrollView>
... Content longer than screen ...
</ScrollView>
</Overlay>
```

Comment: ScrollView is working fine for the content which longer than screen. I think the way that you handling style is wrong. could you share your source code

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced the same issue. using the below code.

```
<Overlay
    isVisible={this.props.visible}
    onBackdropPress={this.props.onClose}
    overlayStyle={styles.overlayStyle}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}>
          ... Content longer than screen ...
      </ScrollView>
</Overlay>
```

I solved this by removing the `flex:1` from the contentContainerStyle props.
Working code

```
<Overlay
    isVisible={this.props.visible}
    onBackdropPress={this.props.onClose}
    overlayStyle={styles.overlayStyle}>
      <ScrollView>
          ... Content longer than screen ...
      </ScrollView>
</Overlay>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue, because one of my scrollviews did not work on android. The issue was that the view with the scroll view was overlaid with absolute positioning. I did that because it was kind of a modal, but needed to open instantly because the user needs to use it very often.

For me the fix to not overlay two views but to conditionally display: none them. So only one view is displayed at a time. This way the components still do not get unmounted and will render very quick.

Sth like this:

```js
<View
    style={{
        flex: 1,
        display: isSelectOpen ? "none" : "flex",
    }}
>
```

Ik that this has nothing todo with the library the OP is using, but this still might help folks with a similar issue.